# 12V 4-pin Noctua NF-A8 on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, temperature, fan

I am using a 12V 4-pin Noctua NF-A8 fan https://noctua.at/en/nf-a8-pwm and want to use the PWM functionality also read the rpm from it. Firstly, I went over dozens of forum discussions on a 5V 4-pin Noctua A4X10 fan which has actually kinda confused me with the fact that do we actually need an NPN transistor circuitry for the PWM pin or not. reading this thread has got a driver circuitry there

[5V 4-pin Noctua A4X10 on Raspberry Pi](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446128/5v-4-pin-noctua-a4x10-on-raspberry-pi/)

The spec pdf says it's not required but they do recommend a CMOS inverter type circuit. regarding the NPN transistor, they printed the same line which idk, of course, a big type error there.

[image]

Can anyone first suggest me the wiring schematic to drive a 12V fan where the supply will be given externally since pi has got 5V as max. I am talking about 12V fan variant here. I will be using either GPIO 12 or 13 for PWM pin since it has got hardware PWM and can operate in the frequecny ranges 21K - 28k as recmmonded in the spec sheet by Noctua.Similary for Fan rpm pin , I guess any gpio pin will be fine right?

As in this forum
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=244194&hilit=5V+4+pin+PWM+Noctua+A4X10+on+Raspberry+Pi&sid

This guy used no driver circuitry for a 5V fan and has got the results too but again I want to reconfirm this that is it important to have a transistor there for the pwm pin if I am choosing a hardware one (GPIO 12 and 13). I dont want to use and boost converter ciruit at the moment and want to keep design simple as I can so I will power this fan externally.

Moreover my aim is to use a temperature sensor which will measure the ambient temperature and then based on its readings the fan speed will be varied using PWM. Can anyone also recommed me a decent temp sensor to for this application and how to code it using python.Sorry I am beginner level rasberry pi and linux user so need help in this project.

Comment: Connect the Noctua's yellow wire to a +12V supply, and its black wire to the supply's ground. Can you probe what voltage comes out of the blue wire?

Answer (score 1):

2N2222 VCE can go beyond 20V so this circuit should work, based on your intent. You can use which ever viable RPi pin you have for both the PWM output and the RPM input pins.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Can I know why the PWM output which in my case is the Fan Rpm pin is used with GPIO 13? I can use any other GPIO pin too right as we want to read its speed.

According to the spec sheet, I am using a 2.7k ohm resistor as recommended there for the tachometer pin, here in the schematic 1.5k seems a lesser value.

Why we are still going with a transistor here, cant I just connect a resistor in series with the GPIO 12 pin? Also, these two hardware pins, are they by default capable of working in the 21kHz ranges and above, or is there any command to set it up?

Comment: Which GPIO will you use for the RPM reading? Which GPIO will you use for the fan's PWM input? The GPIO set on the pic are just placeholders based on your stated GPIO preferences. You can freely change those GPIOs to whatever you intend to use. 2.7k or 1.5k it does not matter as you're only seeing sub-1kHz transition on this pin... in fact, the datasheet specified an 80Hz example which can be considered low frequency. The resistor in Q1's base is there for current limiting and safety purposes.

Comment: For eg I can use GPIO 16 for Rpm and GPIO 12 or 13 for the PWM input. as I did understood the use of resistor for each PWM and RPM pin path when connected to the GPIO pins in Rasberry pin but here I want to know whether Q1 ( transistor) is necessary for the PWM pin. the spec said no special requirements necessary but they recommend too. Moreover, I read 50Hz there using 2.7Khz, why I can't read higher frequencies? yes in the example they show an 86Hz which I don't get why this low or maybe just for demonstration purpose

Comment: Yes, Q1 is necessary for the PWM pin. Q1 enables pulling the blue pin low to GND without making the current pass through your RPi pins (and damaging it). Perhaps you need to multiply 50Hz by 60 to get the instantaneous RPM.

Comment: "RPM" reading x 60 / 2, as per datasheet calculation. What RPM reading do you get following the calculation at 100% PWM duty cycle?

Comment: In this case, the Emitter connection to the ground will be to the 12V -ve end right ? and not to the pi's ground pin such as pin 39 for eg.
Right now I am reading 48hz so 48/2 * 60 gives 1440rpm. I haven't written any script to display rpm yet also I am not controlling pwm pin so I cant really tell.

Comment: No, the collector high level (blue wire) is pulled up at either 3.3V or 5V (page 6 of the datasheet), referenced from the fan's GND, not at 12V. The ground is common for both the RPi and the 12V supply (i.e. their grounds should be connected).

Comment: Fan ground here you mean the -ve end of 12V common with the ground pin from rasberry pi?

Comment: Yes. -VE (GND, 0V) end of the 12V should be common with the Raspberry Pi ground pin to make the circuit work.

Comment: Please take a look here
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=244194&hilit=5V+4+pin+PWM+Noctua+A4X10+on+Raspberry+Pi&sid

this guy says the logic still works wihtout having a transistor in between . Well, I measured voltage across pwm pin and the ground of 12V and it gives me 3.1V . in the spec sheet its mentioned that max voltage is 5.25V  and 0.8V to be lowest. so 3.1V would fit in the range right?

Comment: Yes, 3.1V is within the RPi, input voltage range. Also, If you can powerup the fan by itself, and connect an ammeter between the fan's blue wire and its GND, what current do you measure? If that current does not exceed the RPi's pin current sink capability, then you can do away with Q1, but with a risk/possibility of directing 12V to your RPi in case the fan fails (because we don't know how it behaves when it malfunctions).

Comment: I still highly recommend using Q1, as it prevents your RPi pin from sinking too much current vs if you decide to do away with R1 and Q1.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant here by current sink capability , what I understood is that we shouldn't send higher current than 5mA to the GPIO pwm pin in the pi board? as stated in spec ,  Absolute maximum current sourced: Imax=5mA (short circuit current) so thats why we used resistor so that the pwm pin of fan dosent consume more than 5mA from the pi board. Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: in this thread, the pic says that open collector designs aren't recommended so NPN 2N2222 wont work in this case ?https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446128/5v-4-pin-noctua-a4x10-on-raspberry-pi/