# Tachometer pulses breaking down at lower speeds

Tags: pwm, pulse, hall-effect, tachometer

I have a Noctua 4-pin PWM fan ([PWM datasheet](https://noctua.at/pub/media/wysiwyg/Noctua_PWM_specifications_white_paper.pdf)) from which I'm attempting to calculate RPM using the open collector tachometer output. I'm producing the PWM waveform using a Raspberry Pi Pico.

Here's the schematic I'm using to test:
[image: Schematic]

I don't have a proper oscilloscope, but given it's <100Hz my Bitscope should be sufficient.

Here's a tachometer waveform at 70% duty cycle. Looks alright to me. Similar at 80% and 90%.

[image: regular square waves]

At 60% or so, it becomes irregular, some high levels are 2 or more pulses long:

[image: square waves with irregular high]

Here's 50% duty cycle overlaid with the PWM input:

[image: same image but with regular pwm duty cycle]

An identical model fan exhibits the same issue. A different fan I had on hand (a Ryzen CPU cooler) seems to work fine at 50% duty cycle:

[image: regular pwm and tacho signals]

I get similar results if I pull up to 5V instead of 3V3, or if I connect the tachometer to a GPIO pin and pull up using the internal resistor.

The datasheet recommends Vtacho be 5V. It specifies a maximum of 13V but no minimum. It also says the PWM voltage should be 5V. With the fan powered but the other pins disconnected, I measure 3.2V between Tach and GND. The PWM spec does not define behavior below 20% duty cycle but 60% should be fine.

Based on [another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446128/5v-4-pin-noctua-a4x10-on-raspberry-pi) I also tried raising the PWM signal using a 2N2222 transistor which did not really help:

[image: using transistor]

Would the likely problem be:

- a flaw with the fan
- a problem with my measurement or circuit
- some additional circuitry I need to compensate for *something*?

Comment: What happens if you send a much faster PWM ?

Comment: @tobalt For some reason I had it in my head that setting "25" would correspond to 25kHz, but apparently not. Maybe that was a different piece of software. I will try that tonight, thanks for the tip!